# Why does the child of the object returned by onmouseenter(this) event become null when used in certain ways?

Tags: javascript

I am completely baffled. In the first javaScript example, e.firsElementChild is always null. However, in the second javaScript example, e.firstElementChild always returns the text. Furthermore, if I then take the variable "text" and assign the value of it to e.innerText as shown in javaScript example 3, then e.firstElementChild becomes null again.

html:

```
<span onmouseenter='onMouseEnter(this)'>
        <span>Child</span>
</span>
```

javascript example 1:

```
function onMouseEnter(e){
     e.innerText = e.firstElementChild.innerText;
}
```

javascript example 2:

```
function onMouseEnter(e){
    var text = e.firstElementChild.innerText;
    console.log(text);
}
```

javascript example 3:

```
function onMouseEnter(e){
    var text = e.firstElementChild.innerText;
    e.innerText = text;
}
```

Comment: Because setting `e.innerText` replaces the `<span>` with text, yeah. When you set `e.innerText`, it goes away, and when you don’t set it, it stays. That’s the pattern.

Comment: Oh. how stupid of me. Thanks -Ry-. That explains it. If you present your response as an answer, I'll select it as correct.

Comment: You can post the answer if you want! :) Since you can include the solution as well.